# CKEditor's kcfinder file upload plugin: no images shown

Tags: php, jquery, ckeditor, kcfinder

I'm trying to implement kcfinder into CKEditor so the user can upload some files and implement it into the WYSIWYG editor. I succeeded to manage the "browse on server" button, but when I click it, a pop-up opens and show me some raw php code instead of het image library:

> - @copyright 2010-2014 KCFinder Project * @license http://opensource.org/licenses/GPL-3.0 GPLv3 * @license
>     http://opensource.org/licenses/LGPL-3.0 LGPLv3 * @link
>     http://kcfinder.sunhater.com */ require "core/bootstrap.php"; $browser
>     = "kcfinder\browser"; // To execute core/bootstrap.php on older $browser = new $browser(); // PHP versions (even PHP 4)
>     $browser->action(); ?>

How can I prevent it from doing this?

My files tree:

```
/coaster_cms/js/ckeditor-config.js
/coaster_cms/js/kcfinder/conf/config.php
```

Loading the script files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.7/full/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ckeditor/4.5.4/adapters/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/coaster_cms/js/ckeditor-config.js"></script>
```

My kcfinder config.js file:

```
$_CONFIG = array(


// GENERAL SETTINGS

    'disabled' => false,
    'uploadURL' => "upload",
    'uploadDir' => "",
    'theme' => "default",

    'types' => array(

    // (F)CKEditor types
        'files'   =>  "",
        'flash'   =>  "swf",
        'images'  =>  "*img",

    // TinyMCE types
        'file'    =>  "",
        'media'   =>  "swf flv avi mpg mpeg qt mov wmv asf rm",
        'image'   =>  "*img",
    ),


// IMAGE SETTINGS

    // all image settings are the default ones

);
```

My ckeditor-config.js file:

```
$('textarea.ckeditor').ckeditor({
    language: 'nl',
    height: '400px',
    // speciale karakters niet escapen
    resize_enabled: false,
    entities_latin: false,
    entities_greek: false,
    entities: false,
    basicEntities: false,
    // extra plugins
    filebrowserBrowseUrl: 'http://development.kattenbelletjes.be/coaster_cms/js/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=files',
    filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: 'http://development.kattenbelletjes.be/coaster_cms/js/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images',
    filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl: 'http://development.kattenbelletjes.be/coaster_cms/js/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=flash',
    filebrowserUploadUrl: 'http://development.kattenbelletjes.be/coaster_cms/js/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=files',
    filebrowserImageUploadUrl: 'http://development.kattenbelletjes.be/coaster_cms/js/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images',
    filebrowserFlashUploadUrl: 'http://development.kattenbelletjes.be/coaster_cms/js/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=flash'
});
```

I also tried:

```
$('textarea.ckeditor').ckeditor({
    language: 'nl',
    height: '400px',
    // speciale karakters niet escapen
    resize_enabled: false,
    entities_latin: false,
    entities_greek: false,
    entities: false,
    basicEntities: false,
    // extra plugins
    filebrowserBrowseUrl: 'D:/Websites/Kattenbelletjes/03 - Online/coaster_cms/js/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=files',
    //filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: 'D:/Websites/Kattenbelletjes/03 - Online/coaster_cms/js/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images',
    filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl: 'D:/Websites/Kattenbelletjes/03 - Online/coaster_cms/js/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=flash',
    filebrowserUploadUrl: 'D:/Websites/Kattenbelletjes/03 - Online/coaster_cms/js/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=files',
    filebrowserImageUploadUrl: 'D:/Websites/Kattenbelletjes/03 - Online/coaster_cms/js/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images',
    filebrowserFlashUploadUrl: 'D:/Websites/Kattenbelletjes/03 - Online/coaster_cms/js/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=flash',
});
```

... but I discovered the force isn't with me: I've got an empty pop-up page with no errors at all.

Anybody who could help me please? ;)

**Edit:**

I'm still trying to fix it (first on my local xampp server; "http://development.kattenbelletjes.be"), but I haven't succeed yet. I guess the problem lies in the browse en upload url in ckeditor-config.js. My latest try:

```
filebrowserBrowseUrl: 'D:/Websites/Kattenbelletjes/03 - Online/app/webroot/coaster_cms/js/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=files',
filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: 'D:/Websites/Kattenbelletjes/03 - Online/app/webroot/coaster_cms/js/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images',
filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl: 'D:/Websites/Kattenbelletjes/03 - Online/app/webroot/coaster_cms/js/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=flash',
filebrowserUploadUrl: 'D:/Websites/Kattenbelletjes/03 - Online/app/webroot/coaster_cms/js/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=files',
filebrowserImageUploadUrl: 'D:/Websites/Kattenbelletjes/03 - Online/app/webroot/coaster_cms/js/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images',
filebrowserFlashUploadUrl: 'D:/Websites/Kattenbelletjes/03 - Online/app/webroot/coaster_cms/js/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=flash',
```

Again: I've got the empty pop-up page. When I check Chromes F12 console, an error says now:

> Not allowed to load local resource:
>   file:///D:/Websites/Kattenbelletjes/03%20-%20Online/app/webroot/coaster_cms/js/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images&CKEditor=PostContent&CKEditorFuncNum=0&langCode=nl

Aaaaaargh :)